# Scrape html Twitter followers using R

Tags: html, r, twitter, screen-scraping, httr

I have a continous task that I think can be automated using R. 
Using the twitteR-package I have extracted a list of tweets. Those have been categorized into positive (and neutral) and negative tweets. This have been a manuel task - but I am looking into doing some machine learning on it.

My problem is the reach-part. I want to know not only the number of positive and negative tweets but also the number of people who potentialle have been exposed to the tweet.

There is a way to do this using the twitteR-package, but it is slow, as it requires the machine to sleep between each and every search. And with thousands of tweets this is not a proper way for me.

My thought was therefore if it is possible to extract the number of followers from the html-sourcecode of twitter using the  html <- webpage <- getURL("http://www.twitter.com/AngelHaze") and here extract the number of followers.

Also, on top of this, I want to be able to do this using a vector of URL's ("http://www.twitter.com/AngelHaze") and then combining them into a dataframe with the ScreenName (AngelHaze) and the number of followers. I am from Denmark, so the sourcecode containing the number of followers look like this

a class="ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav u-textUserColor" title="196.262 følgere" data-nav="followers"
href="/AngelHaze/followers""

Where "196.262 følgere" is the relevant part.

Is this possible? And if yes, can anyone help me going?

Best, Sander Ehmsen.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The proper way is to use the api - and respect its limits.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I simply can't understand why this is the case. It is just to extract some text from a html-code that has a more or less similar structure for each case.

Comment: Have you tried extracting it? If not: do so.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am relative new to doing data operations in R (I have only done econometrics in R untill now). I have thus not got a clue on how to perform such an operation. Especially because I turn the webpage into a string.

Comment: Here are some resources: https://www.google.com/search?q=r+xml+parse+webpage. But I guess Twitter.com wouldn't like being scraped anyway.